# Update a relative symlink

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, nsfilemanager

Is there a way how to update a relative symbolic link using  `NSFileManager`?

I have a directory structure like this:

```
data/
  foo/
  bar/
  active -> ./foo
```

`active` is a relative symlink to a directory inside the data structure. It needs to be relative so it won't break between individual app launches.

I'm looking for a way how to change the symlink to point to `bar`. I've tried several approaches:

1) `moveItemAtURL:toURL:` didn't work, because I didn't find a way how to create a `toURL` that's relative to the `data` directory. I tried using  `NSURL`'s `init(string:relativeToURL:)` or constructing it manually (`"./bar"`), but none of this worked (permission problems, etc.).

2) `replaceItemAtURL(_:withItemAtURL:backupItemName:options:resultingItemURL:)` I got a "The file “active” doesn’t exist." even though it does exist.

3) `createSymbolicLinkAtURL(_:withDestinationURL:)` threw a file exists error. D'oh.

I ran out of options. Is there a way how to achieve this?